# Blender 2.8 Copy 50% bone rotation between different local axis

Tags: rigging, bones, constraints, axis

I am trying to make the Bone 1 copy 50% rotation of Bone 2, as below. Mixed axis of the bones make it difficult. Please, what should I do? I spent hours trying, I will do everything you say.

[image: Local Y axis of Bone 1 copies 50% rotation of local Z axis of Bone 2]

I created a fresh armature in simplest way, and found that Local Y axis in bone 1 is Local axis Z in bone 2. Why does this happen? I would expect the bones to have the same local axis alignment?

Is there a way to make Local Y rotation of Bone 1 copy the Local Z rotation of Bone 2 with 50% influence?

Comment: Update: Initially I created the bones in Front view. I re-created the armature in Right view and Local axis for the bones are now aligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the orientation of a bone is not correct you can change it in *Edit* mode with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> (manual), or <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> (automatic). To display the axis go in the *Properties* panel > *Object Data* > *Viewport Display* > *Axes*.

[image]

Now if you want a bone to influence the rotation of another bone, in *Pose* mode, you can give the second bone a *Copy Rotation* constraint (in my case *Space*: *Local Space* - *Local Space*) and reduce the influence value to 50% if it needs to.

[image]

If you want the second bone to copy the rotation of the first one, but on a different axis, use a *Copy Transformation* constraint. For example here I want bone2's Y axis rotation to copy bone1's X axis rotation. I need to set all the values properly.

[image]